# Unselected faces move during Proportional Editing

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, 3d-view, edit-mode

Specifically when I using Proportional Editing with X-Mirror turned on, random faces shift around. Even if I press "G" and don't move my mouse, they still move.

https://imgur.com/a/W6xxYVc

If I disable either one then it's fine, how might I fix this without disabling anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those vertices aren't perfectly mirrored, so they're getting mirrored when you do a transformation. It's Blender fixing your symmetry !
(take a look at the upper lip area, that's where it seems most obvious)

Comment: Yea that was it. Now I'm wondering why the model wasn't perfectly symmetric...